# A word for two people who are alike

Tags: single-word-requests

New friends that feel as though they have known each other forever

Comment: Your title is asking for persons who are similar, but your description is something different. It is about the feeling that two persons have. Can you please edit your question according to your exact needs?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Welcome to ELU. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good questions.

Answer (score 3):

[**Soul mate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soul%20mate) - a person ideally suited to another as a close friend or romantic partner.

> My new friend and I are so alike; we're soul mates.

Two people would feel as though they knew each other because they closely resemble each other, as if they were *meant* to know each other.

Answer (score -1):

I like *Doppelgänger*, literally, the ghostly double of a living person, but used to a remarkably similar person.

Comment: The word "doppelgänger" mostly implies _physical_ similarities.  I think the question is asking more about the connection between people.